# Get attribute of parent using xpath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file that is like this:

```
<PurchaseOrders>
    <PurchaseOrder PoNum="5000" OrderDate="2006-02-18" Status="Unshipped">
        <item>
            <partid>100-100-01</partid>
            <name>Snow Shovel, Basic 22 inch</name>
            <quantity>3</quantity>
            <price>9.99</price>
        </item>
    </PurchaseOrder>
<PurchaseOrders>
... some more Purchase Orders
```

And I would like to return the PurchaseOrder's `PoNum` which contains an item with partid = `"100-100-01"`. So far I have an XPath query that looks like:

```
/PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder[item/partid="100-100-01"]
```

But this only returns the `PurchaseOrder`. How can I get the `PoNum` attribute of this? That is, I want to obtain the value of `PoNum`, which in this case is `"5000"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
/PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder[item/partid="100-100-01"]/@PoNum
```

The `@PoNum` returns the attribute. Basically, use `@` to select attributes.

Comment: So I'm using this XML Developer extension with Eclipse and it keeps telling me that this command returns an empty sequence...

Comment: It works for me, using the same Eclipse extension and your sample document above (correcting the closing tag to `</PurchaseOrders>`). Can you elucidate? Show sample XML and XPath which don't work?

Comment: @YiweiGao, is `PurchaseOrders` actually the root node of the xml document? The question suggests that there may actually be multiple `PurchaseOrders` - ie there are multiple roots or there is a different root node. You could try starting the xpath with `//` instead of `/`.